# Truncated Binomial Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Can the truncated binomial series be expressed as a closed form
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} x^{k}
\end{align}

Comment: It can be expressed in terms of the Hypergeometric function.

Comment: I believe there is a simpler form.